# PL/SQL Creating a trigger that checks SYSDATE against a range of date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Creating a trigger that blocks updates for Table in period of one week after every first of january every year.

I try to take in values for 01 jan as a char of 0101, and trying to add 7 days but to no avail. Is there a way to do this ?

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  first_jan date;
BEGIN
   first_jan := to_date('0101','DDMM');
   IF(SYSDATE < first_jan+7) THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Error Message');
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this do what you want?

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   first_jan := to_date('0101','DDMM');
   IF (extract(month from SYSDATE) = 1 and
       extract(day from sysdate) <= 7
      ) THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Error Message');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! This does do what I want, but I am wondering if there is another way around it

Comment: @Anthony . . . I have no idea what you are referring to.  This answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method for doing this is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BU
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMDD')) <= 107 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Error Message');
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEE_BU;
```

Another alternative is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BU
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) = 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Error Message');
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEE_BU;
```

And YAA (Yet Another Alternative) is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BU
BEFORE UPDATE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMW')) = 11 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Error Message');
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEE_BU;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3e0e8fc4046c59f0fcfb5cfd5d5286f)

Answer (score 0):

DDD is the day of the year.

```
SQL> select date '2019-01-03' from dual;

DATE'2019
---------
03-JAN-19

SQL> select to_char(date '2019-01-03','ddd') from dual;

TO_
---
003

SQL> select to_char(date '2019-02-03','ddd') from dual;

TO_
---
034
```

That's a one liner you can slot into your IF statement

Answer (score 0):

The date 1 Jan is available by truncating sysdate to year: "trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')". So, in this case you get the desired result with no additional variables and a single function call by

```
if sysdate < trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')+7 
then 
    raise application_error(-20004, 'error message'); 
end if;
```